# How can I force TestNG test result to pass?

Tags: java, testng

I'm using an external place to document which test has passed and which has failed (TestRail) and I want to to make test which documented as passed (in TestRail) to pass in the running without actually run them.

I don't want to skip them because there are other test which depends on these tests.
I know I can check if they passed in every test and make the whole test inside a big **if** but I want to find a way to make it simple in the @BeforeMethod.

```
@BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
public synchronized void beforeMethod(Method method) {
     method.pass();
}

@BeforeTest(alwaysRun = true)
public synchronized void beforeMethod(ITestContext context) {
     TestRunner runner = (TestRunner) context;
     runner.addPassedTest(testNGMethod,((TestRunner) context).addPassedTest();
}
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you are trying to do. Doesn't it defeat the purpose of having tests if you don't run them but just say "passed last time, so let's say it passed again"? What if the code under test changes? You may have a test that would catch a bug but you disable the tests? And honestly, tests depending on each other sounds like a terrible test setup to me. Each test should be independent. Are you struggling with a lot of slow tests, like having too many integration tests and not enough unit tests? You could look into test avoidance, but I'd rather clean up my tests.

Comment: Forcing a test to "pass" if it fails defeats the purpose of the test itself indeed, just as Robert says. Either delete the test, ignore it, or make sure your code is in such shape the test never fails.

Comment: Off course I don't want not to test every test that passed once, I want to use this option only on the same deployment and after fixing tests which failed but didn't supposed to.
The dependencies are important because if the basic functionality of a feature is failing, the more complex tests will surely fail and I don't want to waste time on checking them. @Robert

Comment: Yes, I just added it as an answer.
Thanks @kissu

Comment: It's really not a good idea to just run the tests that failed before the fix - changes to your code could actually make different tests fail (because a fix in one place could break another place in your code).  If your tests take to long, that's a topic to work on.